# Pass complex type to HttpGet method in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API and I'm having problems receiving my parameter in my controller method. I do receive the `request` parameter in the `RetrieveMultipleEmployees` method, but the `Where` property is null.

The sequence is as follows:

1. Create the `StandardRequest<Employee>` with the `Where` property defined.
2. Call the `RetrieveMultipleEmployeesAsync` method and pass the created `StandardRequest<Employee>`.
3. The `RetrieveMultipleEmployeesAsync` calls the `RetrieveMultipleEmployeesRoute` method and passes the request along.
4. The `RetrieveMultipleEmployees` controller method gets hit, the parameter is not null but the `Where` property is null.

Here is what I have:

Base controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("data/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/{action}")]
public class BaseController<TController> : ControllerBase
{
    private IMediator _mediatorInstance;
    protected IMediator _mediator => _mediatorInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();

    private ILogger<TController> _loggerInstance;
    protected ILogger<TController> _logger => _loggerInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<TController>>();
}
```

EmployeesController:

```
public class EmployeesController : BaseController<EmployeesController>
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("retrievemultipleemployees")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RetrieveMultipleEmployees([FromQuery] StandardRequest<Employee> request)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(new EmployeeQueries.RetrieveMultipleQuery() { Request = request });

        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

StandardRequest:

```
public class StandardRequest<TEntity>
{
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Where { get; set; }
}
```

Url:

```
public static string RetrieveMultipleEmployeesRoute(StandardRequest<Employee> request)
{
    var url = $"data/v1/employees/retrievemultipleemployees?{request}";

    return url;
}
```

Request:

```
public async Task<StandardResult<List<EmployeeModel>>> RetrieveMultipleEmployeesAsync(StandardRequest<Employee> request)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(EmployeeRoutes.RetrieveMultipleEmployeesRoute(request));

    return await response.ToStandardResultAsync<List<EmployeeModel>>();
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Might it be something in my API setup?

Some advise on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your URL end up looking like? You can't just convert an expression to a string and get a valid URL, much less a URL that can be bound to a DTO. What you try to do is already implemented in OData anyway. Operations are passed as separate query parameters, not as a serialized object, eg `GET serviceRoot/People?$filter=FirstName eq 'Scott'`

Comment: Instead of trying to invent your own query syntax why not create a GraphQL or OData service?

Comment: I'm new to Web API's so still learning. I'm using components from previous projects and trying to get them to work. I have never used GraphQL or OData before but I'll look into that thank you. Also the URL ends up looking like this client side: "data/v1/employees/retrievemultipleemployees?Common.Requests.StandardRequest`1[Employee]" and looks the same when it hits the controller but the where property is null.

Comment: If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.So it is not a good choice to pass a complex model with query string.You'd better use Httppost request to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code looks suspect:

```
public static string RetrieveMultipleEmployeesRoute(StandardRequest<Employee> request)
{
    var url = $"data/v1/employees/retrievemultipleemployees?{request}";

    return url;
}
```

That is simply going to call `ToString()` on `request`, resulting in something like this being returned (assuming you haven't overridden it to create an actual query string):

```
data/v1/employees/retrievemultipleemployees?StandardRequest`[Employee]
```

Which is clearly bogus. You're going to need to convert that incoming `request` into a proper query string using something like [QueryString.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring.create?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for example.

Comment: I'll do some research on this and try it out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

*Is recommended to put your ComplexObject into a Class Library common to both projects the Client and the API*

REQUESTOR

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

private readonly string ExtractEpridDbcisinfo = "http://localhost:5281/domething";
public void consumeAPI(){

 Uri uri = new Uri(*yourBaseURI*);
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string sParam1= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(complexobject,typeof(ComplexObject) ,null);

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"?paramComplexObject={sParam1}").Result;  
.
.
.
```

GET REST API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("domething")]
public IActionResult Index(string paramComplexObject){

 ComplexObject complexObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ComplexObject>(paramComplexObject);

.
.
.
```